# Hair loss on stray cat's head behind ears

Tags: cats, veterinarian, strays

There are two stray cats (around 6-7 months old I guess) near my house. I often feed them boiled chicken or cooked egg yolk. About 10 days ago I started giving them Whiskas Dry Kitten Food.

Few days ago I observed a hair loss small spot on one of the cat's head (Zag). And now it has grown in size. 
I tried to look for fleas or ticks but couldn't find much, as he doesn't allow me to search through his hair a lot. There's a similar small stripe like spot on his body, but it's small in size now.
I know ideally I'm supposed to take Zag to the Vet, but being a student I'm really low on budget. Also I can't take them in because of my apartment issues.

Is it possible that he might be having an allergy to the cat food? His brother (Zig) is fine and has no such signs of hair loss. They sleep together most of the times, so if it would have been an infection it should have spread to his brother too, right?
Zag's behaviour is pretty normal he plays a lot and grooms himself too.
On the contrary, once I started feedinng Zig catfood he has become more playful.

I would be grateful if anyone having any clue about such hair loss pattern could tell me what it could be.

Thanks
[image]
[image]
[image]

Zig (His Brother)
[image]

Comment: the cat have very large ears so they might get too hot in the sun or too cold at night,do both cats have big ears or only this one.

Comment: no, his brother's ears are slighly small (maybe few millimeters)
I added his picture too

Answer (score 4):

The spot behind the right ear of your cat does look like an insect bite, most likely after a tick.

You will find a tiny bit of swelling in the skin of your cat right where the bald spot is. Most of my cats have had this every summer.

It does not look infected so you do not need to treat it, but to avoid this in the future you can get [Frontline](https://www.amazon.co.uk/FRONTLINE-Spot-Cats-6-Pipettes/dp/B0014WJAOU) to keep the ticks away.

The treatment is effective against fleas and external parasites too.

The spot might be a skin puncture by a claw from another cat too, so it is good if you keep an eye on it if it gets infected.